# Python crawler in an ajax website (modem-router settings)

Tags: python, ajax, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, urllib

How can I create a python crawler for an ajax website that has same url all the time?
Is it possible?

Should I go step by step from the index page to the page that I want and wish for the best that everything works fine? (or there are other ways to heaven too?)

---

edit:
The url is http://192.168.1.1/
I actually want to access my router settings.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, if you want to get a proper answer you need to update your question with the code that you have tried so far and tell us about its problems. Or a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about what you are going to achieve.

Comment: The question is complete. I just want to know if it's possible or not! I didn't try to because I don't know how to do it. We always give a url to our crawler and ask for a piece of content. But I don't have any url except the index page of that website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "Yes, it's possible"

You can open your browsers console (network tab), and then look for api url which will be called by frontend scripts and contains needed data.
Responses are usually json/xml so you can parse them easily

Comment: So this means navigating in a browser and writing down the path(&...) and then trying the same thing in programming lanuage. right?